# How do I add utility methods to jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I typically use the below design pattern to create jQuery plugins (http://jsbin.com/vegevido/1/).

For this one, I wish to add a utility method which will not be applied to elements like normal jQuery plugins, but could be used by the parent script.

As shown below, I have added the utility method `multiply` which is accessed by the parent script using `$('#elem').makeRed('multiply',5,3)`.

Is this how I should be implementing this?  It seems like it would be better to access this method using something like `myPlugin.multiple(5,3)` as it has nothing to do with `#elem`.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            (function($){
                var defaults = {};

                var methods = {
                    init : function (options) {
                        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                        return this.each(function () {
                            $(this).css('color', 'red');
                        });
                    },
                    makeBlue : function () {
                        $(this).css('color', 'blue');
                    },
                    multiply : function (x,y) {
                        return x*y;
                    },
                    destroy : function () {
                        return this.each(function () {});
                    }
                };

                $.fn.makeRed = function(method) {
                    if ( methods[method] ) {
                        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
                    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
                    } else {
                        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.makeRed' );
                    }    
                };

                }(jQuery));
            $(function(){
                var myPlugin=$('#elem').makeRed();
                $('#makeBlue').click(function() {$('#elem').makeRed('makeBlue');});
                $('#multiply').click(function() {
                    console.log(myPlugin);
                    alert($('#elem').makeRed('multiply',5,3));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="elem">Some Text</div>

        <button id="makeBlue">makeBlue</button>
        <button id="multiply">multiply</button>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common pattern is to add it to the plugin definition like

```
$.makeRed = {
    multiply: function (x, y) {
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5KDnY/2/)

This is how jQuery UI exposes utility methods like [$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, settings )](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

Comment: Thanks Arun,  The first way works great.  Trying the second "cleaner" way.  Where does this script go?  How is it called?

Comment: @user1032531 checkout the fiddle

Comment: The fiddle doesn't use `$.makeRed = {multiply: function (x, y) {return x * y;}}`, or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I see, I just call it using `$.makeRed.multiply(5, 3)`.  Very nice!  Why would one ever want to use the first way?

Comment: @user1032531 I think I'll remove the first one